# Is it possible to set the default as “No” for "display this list on the quick launch " while creating a list?

Tags: 2010, list, quick-launch

[image]When you create a new List, the default to include in Quick Launch is YES, which causes "LISTS" to appear in the left navigation. You have to go back and change it to NO. If we want LISTS to **not** appear in their left navigation/quick launch, can we just make the default NO?

1. Is it possible to set default `No` using OOTB?
2. If not how can we achieve this using custom solutions.

I have come across the solution to entirely hide the Quick Launch. But that is not what I want.

tried using javascript but it is not working. i am assuming that the page uses v4 master page;so wrote it on v4.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var no = document.getElementById("onetidDisplayOnLeftNo")
    if (no != null) {
        $("#onetidDisplayOnLeftNo").attr("checked", "checked");
        $("#onetidDisplayOnLeftYes").attr("checked", " ");
```

Comment: The version is  2010 with sp1

Comment: do you mean you want to hide items under " Recent " tab of quick launch?

Comment: no; When we create a list, I want the default option to be "no" in"display this list on quick launch" under navigation. Added screen for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reality what happens if you create for instance a list named *Tasks*, is that two extra navigation items are added to quick launch navigation: a header labeled *Lists*, and a child of it named *Tasks*.

To answer your points

> 1. Is it possible to set default No using OOTB?

If you're in control of the list template used for the list (so it's a custom list definition), you can try using the *OnQuickLaunch* attribute available on [ListTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms462947(v=office.14).aspx)

<del>If you mean to override the default setting for OOB lists, answer is no. The easiest solution for that would be to inject some JavaScript in the list creation page to click 'No' by default instead.</del>

> 2. If not how can we achieve this using custom solution

**Updated**: JavaScript can't be used in this case, because the page uses a Silverlight component by default

<del>JavaScript approach could be quite easy to achieve.</del>

The solution requires a Web EventReceiver that hooks ListAdding event, and changes the behavior by setting *OnQuickLaunch* property on the list to *false*.
[Working with ListAdding and ListDeleting Events](http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/3851211/Working-with-ListAdding-and-ListDeleting-Events.htm)

Comment: I tried using javascipt; wrote it on v4 master page. but somehow could not capture the id of radio button. Further to add, I was not able to select the radio button using developer tools. I am using IE11.Added the script in question.

Comment: right, this is one of the few places where Silverlight was used instead. By default will try to show the Silverlight version of this page, and JS isn't an option then.
I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can add an Event Receiver with following event you can set `OnQuickLaunch=false`  so for every list you create the ER will be executed and you can hide list through it

```
 public override void ListAdding(SPListEventProperties properties)
 {
            properties.List.OnQuickLaunch = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not posible OOTB.
   Only way you can check this "No" while creating a list or library, just press "More Options" button:

[image]

When you Name your list and select that option to show in the left navigation, so you don't need to go to List or Library settings to change it after creation.

Comment: I want the default behaviour to be selected as "No" so that if user creates a list without going to more options the list does not shows up in the quick launch